# Natural Deduction Proof with double quantifier (predicate logic)

Tags: proof, deduction, predicate-logic

Premise: (∃y)(∀x)(Px v Py)

Conclusion: ~(∀y)(~Py)

I'm starting out assuming the negation, i.e., (∀y)(~Py).

But then I'm unsure how to find a contradiction within that subderivation. Here's what I've done so far, i know it's wrong because I can't do ∃E

```
1. (∃y)(∀x)(Px v Py)       Premise
|  2. (∀y)(~Py)            Assume
|  3. ~Pa                  UI 2
|  4. (∃y)(∀x)(Px v Py)    Reiterate
|  b|  5. (∀x)(Px v Pb)    Assume
|   |  6. Pa v Pb          UE 5
|   |  7. Pb               vE 3,6
```

Comment: In general: for Hw problems, please show your current line of thought first.

Comment: You can expand on step 5 a bit more - think about what it means for Everything to be P, and how b relates to that.

Comment: Assume **(∀y)(~Py)**. From premise you have **(∀x)(Px v Pa)** from which **(Pa v Pa)** from which **Pa**. But from assumption **~Pa**.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> 1. (∃y)(∀x)(Px v Py)       Premise
> |  2. (∀y)(~Py)            Assume
> |  3. ~Pa                  UI 2
> |  4. (∃y)(∀x)(Px v Py)    Reiterate
> |  b|  5. (∀x)(Px v Pb)    Assume
> |   |  6. Pa v Pb          UE 5
> |   |  7. Pb               vE 3,6
> ```

That is a *disjunctive syllogism* `vS` rather than *disjunction elimination* `vE`. Well, if you are allowed to use that rule, you may.

However, as it stands your main issue lies in not being able to derive a *contradiction*.  It would be best to have somehow derived `~Pb`, so...

Do not immediately use UE on an arbitrary variable (`a`).  Instead, be patient and wait until you have the witness for an existential (`b`).

```
|_ 1. (∃y)(∀x)(Px v Py)        Premise
|   |_ 2. (∀y)(~Py)            Assume
|   |  3. (∃y)(∀x)(Px v Py)    Reiterate 1
|   |[b]|_ 4. (∀x)(Px v Pb)    Assume
|   |   |  5. (∀y)(~Py)        Reiterate 2
|   |   |  6. ~Pb              UE 5
|   |   |  7. Pb v Pb          UE 4
|   |   |  8. Pb               vS 6,7 
:   :   :
```